# Legends for plot lines aren't visible

Tags: r, quantmod, quantitative-finance

Trying to add a box of legends where what value each coloured lines indicate will be clearly mentioned. But after trying so many times, I still couldn't make it visible.

I have tried-

1. changing the x and y value within the legend()
2. exporting as pdf or jpg
3. restarting the graphics driver `dev.off()` and updating the library
4. updating the preview

I am expecting a Legend Box stating what each coloured line indicates(ex. Opening Price, Closing Price).

My Code:

```
#install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

symbol <- "AAPL"
start_date <- as.Date("2023-04-11")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-05-11")


getSymbols(Symbols = symbol, src = "yahoo", from = start_date, to = end_date)
opening_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Open", sep = ".")]
closing_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Close", sep = ".")]
adjusted_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Adjusted", sep = ".")]
high_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "High", sep = ".")]
low_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Low", sep = ".")]
volume <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Volume", sep = ".")]

#this would print default table of stock data
#print(stock_data)

stock_data_df <- data.frame(
  opening_prices, 
  closing_prices, 
  adjusted_prices, 
  high_prices, 
  low_prices, 
  volume
)

print(stock_data_df)

# Create a new plot with the opening prices
plot(opening_prices, type = "l", col = "blue", main = paste("Stock Prices for", symbol))

# Add lines for closing, adjusted, high, and low prices
lines(closing_prices, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(adjusted_prices, type = "l", col = "green")
lines(high_prices, type = "l", col = "orange")
lines(low_prices, type = "l", col = "purple")

legend(x = "topright",
       legend = c("Opening Prices", "Closing Prices", "Adjusted Prices", "High Prices", "Low Prices"), 
       lty = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
       col = c("blue", "red", "green", "orange", "purple"))
```

**Current Output in Plots(R Studio):**

[image: Current Output in Plots(R Studio):]

**Output of dput(opening_prices)**

[image: Output of dput(opening_prices)]

Comment: I'm not willing to install quantmod. However, calling your `legend` code after calling `plot(1)` results in the desired legend. You should add the output of `dput(opening_prices)` to your question.

Comment: Can you just copy past the dput output ? So we can rebuild your data

Comment: Got my desired output by using ggplot. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

In fact your plot is an eXtensible Time Series (xts) plot and for that type of plot
the `xts` package provided an `addLegend` function for your purpuse ..

`addLegend(legend.loc = "center", legend.names = NULL, col = NULL, ncol = 1, on = 1, ...)`

below the plot in your case

```r
library(quantmod)
symbol <- "AAPL"
start_date <- as.Date("2023-04-11")
end_date <- as.Date("2023-05-11")
getSymbols(Symbols = symbol, src = "yahoo", from = start_date, to = end_date)
#> [1] "AAPL"
stock_data=AAPL # stock_data was not defined in the question code 
opening_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Open", sep = ".")]
closing_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Close", sep = ".")]
adjusted_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Adjusted", sep = ".")]
high_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "High", sep = ".")]
low_prices <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Low", sep = ".")]
volume <- stock_data[, paste(symbol, "Volume", sep = ".")]
stock_data_df <- data.frame(
  opening_prices, 
  closing_prices, 
  adjusted_prices, 
  high_prices, 
  low_prices, 
  volume
)

# Create a new plot with the opening prices
plot(opening_prices, type = "l", col = "blue", main = paste("Stock Prices for", symbol))
# Add lines for closing, adjusted, high, and low prices
lines(closing_prices, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(adjusted_prices, type = "l", col = "green")
lines(high_prices, type = "l", col = "orange")
lines(low_prices, type = "l", col = "purple")
addLegend(legend.loc = "topleft",
          legend = c("Opening Prices", "Closing Prices", "Adjusted Prices", "High Prices", "Low Prices"), 
          lty = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
          col = c("blue", "red", "green", "orange", "purple"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>